# What is the best method to have Dynamic CSS?

Tags: css

I have the theme options ready. i am able to save the user provided color to database. But problem i am facing is how to use info to generate css?

will be great if some one can explain with one example.
there are many methods listed like using a .php file as css, inline styles etc..but it's all confusing.

thanks for your time

Comment: Have you looked up [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style)?

Answer (score 1):

For better and worse doing dynamic CSS is not the "WordPress way". If you have a long list of CSS related options that the user may override, you should serve their defaults in a static CSS, and override when needed by inlined CSS.

Comment: thank you :).  i also feel like inline method is the best option!.